# If my android is connected to my pc at work, can admin look through the files of my phone? If so what can i do about it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, android

I usually have my phone connected to my PC (windows 7). Just wondering about the ways that an admin can potentially see my files. If so, can I do something about it.

Comment: A user can access all files located or connected to a system where they are an Administrator. If you don't want to provide access to your files on your phone, don't connect the phone, to the computer.

Comment: Why is the phone connected to the PC, just to charge it? Just turn off USB storage / MTP

Comment: I actually use it as my thumbdrive and update my files (sometimes private) throughout the day. Really for convenience as I connect it to my laptop at home and car radio using it for the same purpose.

Comment: I guess you could do some sort of file level encryption (e.g. an encrypted archive to store files), but once that data is decrypted, your data is potentially exposed... So I pretty much agree with Ramhound

Comment: If you want to make the files hidden as the system hides files you can use this. cmd.exe then run the command to cd into the dir of your usb then this command `attrib FILENAME.EXT +s +h` this will make the file hidden you can do this with folders too with `attrib FOLDER +s +h` this would make if if they were just browsing through to be hidden the way to view the files would be to use show hidden files in the explained [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7) hope this possibly helps you a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Anything you can access on your phone while it is connected to the computer can potentially be accessed by anyone with sufficient rights on the network. There is nothing you can do about this except for permanently disconnecting the machine from the network or never connecting your phone to the computer.

There is also a possibility that logging software that watches for access to external devices has been installed, this is typically known as Endpoint Protection software. This software *could* retain copies of all files copied to or from external devices.  Most modern workplaces need to protect themselves from confidential data being leaked and these tools will generally give them this level of access.

There is nothing you can do about this, the moment you are able to read and write files on your device is the same moment your network administrator also has access if they so desire. It's not *your* machine, you are simply using work hardware to do your job, and the machine administrator has the ability to do what they need or want with the software and data on it.

Hiding files, encrypting them or anything else is useless if you want to access those files on the computer. You can encrypt a file using software on your phone itself and it could be safe, but the moment you decrypt it to transfer it to your computer it is no longer in your control.

Comment: Upvoting but adding a note: I would make the ending say "it is no longer in your sole control".  You will still have control over the file; you just won't have exclusive control, because someone else could also have control.